# I killed my Linux Mint with XStoreName in a loop, how do I fix it?

Tags: c++, linux, xorg

I killed my Linux Mint with XStoreName in a loop, how do I fix it?

I have killed my Linux Mint 18.03 Cinnamon with XStoreName(dpy, w, fps); in Eclipse running my cpp file.
(I wanted to output frames (per second) in the title bar.)
(When I first put XStoreName outside a loop, everything worked fine.)

```
//other stuff

char msg[20];
int fps=0;
while (1) {
   //other stuff

   sprintf(msg,"%d",fps);
   //XDrawString(display, w, gc, 10, 10, msg, strlen(msg));
   XDeleteProperty(dpy, w, XA_WM_NAME);
   XStoreName(dpy, w, msg);
   fps++;
}
```

Linux totally froze and now when I reboot i get a black screen.

I can't even do ctrl-alt-f1 for a tty.

Advanced options on boot are available , and I go to root command line.

I have tried:

```
rm -rf /tmp/*
rm -rf /tmp/.*
sudo apt-get install --reisntall xorg
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xorg
```

and same after: su myusername

It didn't work.

Comment: I don't think running this program is related to the failure.  Did the user running the program have write permission to the video sub-system?  That is, was it running as `root`?  Try using the "recovery" option on `grub`.  It may also be an issue with the display manager, e.g.: lightdm / gdm.  *Maybe* try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm`. See also: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/12/how-to-change-default-display-manager.html

Comment: Someone more familiar than I with X programming can probably help with fixing the code (probably need to throttle the update rate because `while (1)` is probably beyond X's capability to handle) but fixing the computer in the aftermath is probably better served by one of the more-Linux-y parts of the Stack Exchange. I agree with @Kingsley: This shouldn't have cratered the PC without help.

Comment: I am running Linux in VMware and same thing happened to Ubuntu but it recovered after few reboots...

Comment: some sort of `sleep` command is required here, but I'm not familiar with xorg programming and their libraries. Probably something like `sleep(1000)` (for 1000 milliseconds). at the bottom of your loop. You can tune that number once you get things under control. Good luck.